# Udp multicast group in Windows Store and Windows Desktop apps

Tags: networking, udp, windows-store-apps, multicast

I'm try to build up the communication between a Windows desktop app and a group of Windows Store and/or Windows Store apps, using UDP multicast groups.
A communication module exists in all applications, but there is a problem: Desktop and Phone apps use classes from System.Net namespace, and the Store app uses classes from the Windows.Networking namespace.
It seems that the Store app doesn't receive any datagram, since the handler for the datagram received is never called (looking to Wireshark tracing, I found that datagrams for the specified multicast group and the specified port arrive from a machine to another, so there isn't a network problem).
It seems that classes from the two namespaces are incompatible, so I should use the same namespaces in all applications, but seems that the use of System.net in Windows Store apps is discouraged, or impossible. Also, it seems that the use of Windows.Networking in Windows Desktop apps is impossible.
Am I wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrong. A UDP datagram sent by any piece of software should be receivable by any other piece of software as long as both have functional IP stacks underneath. The Internet proves this every second.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The fact is, the code I'm working on is really messed up, and I often don't see mistakes. This was a matter of mistakes.